# Find the Characteristic Curve of the PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $x=x(s),y=y(s),z=z(s) ,s\epsilon\Bbb R $ , be the characteristic curve of the PDE

> $z_x + z_y -z  = 0$
>
> passing through the curve $x=0 , y=t , z=t^2 , t\epsilon\Bbb R$
>
> Then  what are the characteristics

Comment: The general solution to your PDE is wrong.  It should be $z(x,y) = F(y-x) e^x,$ where $F$ is an another smooth function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a PDE $a(x,y,z) z_x + b(x,y,z) z_y  = c(x,y,z),$ you can obtain the characteristic by solving the ODE's 
$$
\frac{dx}{ds} = a(x,y,z), \ \ \ \frac{dy}{ds} =b(x,y,z)  \ \ \ \frac{dz}{ds} = c(x,y,z).
$$ 
You have $a(x,y,z)=1, \ \ b(x,y,z)=1, \ \ c(x,y,z)=z.$  Therefore $x=s+c_1(t)$, $y=s+c_2(t)$ and $z=c_3(t) e^s.$   When $s=0,$ you want to be along the prescribed curved $x=0,y=t,z=t^2,$  Therefore we get $$x=s, \ \ y = s+t,  \ \ z=t^2 e^s.$$  Solving $z$ in terms of $x,y$ we get $s=x,$ $t=y-x,$ so that $$z(x,y)=(y-x)^2 e^x.$$   This is is precisely the solution for your prescribed data.

Comment: Your ODE for z is $dz/ds = z,$ which has solution $z(s)= C e^s.$

Comment: But how could we reach at the right option?

Comment: The correct option (a)-(d) is cleverly disguised (or derived in a way that is not very efficient).  The correct option is (a).   Substitute $s=0$ to see it.

Comment: Actually, none of the results (a)-(b) above are characteristic.